# How to use broswerified node module into another JavaScript file

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, browserify

I have a node module file which I have broswerifed using [browserify](http://browserify.org/)

```
// myMath.js file
// --------------

module.exports = {
  add: function(a, b){
    return a + b;
  }
}
```

Now to use it in another JavaScript application, I am using following code

```
// index.js file
// -------------

var myMath = require("./myMath");

var result = myMath.add(1, 2);
console.log("the result is", result);
```

Now I am using broswerify:

```
browserify index.js -o app.js
```

But this apporach requires involving *index.js* file as well. **Is there any way to directly include broswerified myMath.js file into my JavaScript application ??**

Comment: `browserify myMath.js -o app.js` ? or have I missed something?

Comment: @benhowdle89: I have tired that too. But with this approach I am not able to utilize browserified file into my JS application.